# kendogrid inline batch editing, how to do all crud operations on final submission.(Without using incell edit)

Tags: kendo-grid, inline-editing

Is there any way to implement Inline Batch editing using kendo grid ? I want a grid which supports inline editing and wants do all operations offline, On final submitting it should complete all curd operations at one time
(when calling grid.savechanges()).

Comment: Is any one having idea or working on this?

Comment: Not sure if you actually meant to write "submission" instead of "submittion"?